Is there a way to capture local & global variable values at each call stack of an Android native process?
At Linux, I can send "kill -6 " to generate a core file, and load it in gdb. Within gdb, I can see the local and global variables at each call stack.
From my checking Android online document, it seems Android does not support this. The core dumps are text files, not ELF files.
I see User debuggers mentioning to debug Android process using lldb, but it is not clear to me whether scoping core dump is also supported.
How can I capture local & global variable values at each call stack of an Android native process?
Thanks!
